# Suitable AWS or Colab account suggestion

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtual-machine, google-colaboratory

I am looking to subscribe to a virtual machine with either AWS/Colab/Azure/PaperSpace or any other suitable site. I need a platform to run java program and a mysql database (to which my Java program will also connect to).
Figuring out which plan would be suitable and cost effective is proving to be challenging. For example, in Colab the subscription plans mentioned are based on per unit of compute. However not sure how one unit if compute is being calculated. Plans for AWS are so many that it's confusing to understand which one would be most suitable for me.

Can anyone with experience in using online VMs please guide which plan (in preferably Colab or AWS) would be suitable for me based on the requirement I have posted above?

Comment: Hi, Reshma. The question is open-ended, and I've tried my best to answer it from my own point of view. See below for my answer which I hope helps you. If you need a clarification please post a comment or edit your question with new details.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a virtual machine subscription to one of four cloud service providers. Here I have summarized their services:

- [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/) - general cloud platform with support for [Java](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/language/java/) and [MySQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/)
- [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/intro/azure-developer-overview) - general cloud platform with support for [Java](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/resources/developers/java/) and [MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/mysql)
- [Colab](https://colab.google/) - hosted Jupyter notebook service
- [PaperSpace](https://www.paperspace.com/) - AI model development and hosting

You say you need to run a **Java** program and a **MySQL** database. Because of their support for your chosen tools, I think the best choice here is **AWS** or **Azure**.

Colab and PaperSpace appear to be specialized for development of data science and artificial intelligence projects. You don't mention these requirements so I think these service providers will not help.

---

On **AWS** a good place to start may be the **[Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)** service because it allows you to manage a environment that includes an [**EC2** compute instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ec2/) to [host your Java program](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html) and an [**RDS** database instance](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/) to [host your MySQL database](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html).

Elastic Beanstalk has no extra charge, but you do need to choose a **plan** to suit the EC2 and RDS usage.

[RDS offers **limited free usage**](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/free/) for the first 12 months. A good place to start may be the **db.t3.micro** instance size with 20GB of gp2 storage. After 12 months you will start to [pay **on-demand** rates](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/), and how much you pay depends on how long you use it. The RDS pricing page says that if you keep these resources running for a whole month in the US East N. Virginia region you would pay about **15 USD** per month. If you turn it off when you are not using it you will pay less.

EC2 has a [similar introductory free offer](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/). A good place to start may be the **t3.micro** instance size with 10GB of gp2 storage. The monthly [on-demand pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) for these resources in US East N. Virginia would be about **7 USD**. Again, you only pay when the instance is turned on.

However you use your AWS account, you can use the [billing console](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-billing/), [cost explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/), and [billing alarms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) to track your spending and avoid surprises.

---

I haven't used **Azure**, but I believe it offers a similar deal for new developers. Its [free tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/) includes for 12 months a **B1s** size compute instance and **B1MS** size [database instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/how-to-deploy-on-azure-free-account) with 32GB storage. Instead of Elastic Beanstalk here you can use the [**Azure App Service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will explore Elastic Beanstalk first. I do agree that the question is too generic. I am new to these platforms and trying to figure out. I may have followup queries. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks, Reshma. Please upvote and accept the answer if it was useful. Stack Overflow's Q and A format isn't always a good fit for the open-ended questions, but there are other places. You could join [TechStudySlack](https://techstudyslack.com/) to ask questions in a more fluid chatroom style. Adrian Cantrill founded it and explains the motivation in his [LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/adriancantrill_studying-aws-is-something-which-should-improve-activity-6902885519018074112-3f88/).